# Pivot report problem cause by multiplied rows from merge (Excel)

Tags: excel, merge, pivot, powerquery

I have a table below, which is an result of merging 2 tables of BU(business unit) and CC(cost centre) (each of them has multiple accouns and "flows") based on some allocation key (as percent), that define how much "costs" of CC is allocated to BU. Since each BU has 3 CCs, my merge has return table like this:

| BU/CC | Account | Flows | PNL 2023 | Alloc.CC | Alloc.Allocation Key | CU.BU/CC | CU.Account | CU.Flows | CC PNL 2023 | INDIRECT | Indirect_costs | ADJUSTED_BU_PNL_2023 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Business Unit 1 | Account 1 | 1) Project Revenue | 120000 | Cost center 1 | 30 | Cost center 1 | Account 1 | 1) Project Revenue | 0 | Indirect Costs | 0 | 120000 |
| Business Unit 1 | Account 1 | 1) Project Revenue | 120000 | Cost center 2 | 30 | Cost center 2 | Account 1 | 1) Project Revenue | 0 | Indirect Costs | 0 | 120000 |
| Business Unit 1 | Account 1 | 1) Project Revenue | 120000 | Cost center 3 | 40 | Cost center 3 | Account 1 | 1) Project Revenue | 0 | Indirect Costs | 0 | 120000 |
| Business Unit 1 | Account 1 | 2) Project Cost | -80000 | Cost center 1 | 30 | Cost center 1 | Account 1 | 2) Project Cost | 0 | Indirect Costs | 0 | -80000 |
| Business Unit 1 | Account 2 | 1) Project Revenue | 600000 | Cost center 2 | 30 | Cost center 2 | Account 2 | 1) Project Revenue | 0 | Indirect Costs | 0 | 600000 |
| Business Unit 1 | Account 2 | 1) Project Revenue | 600000 | Cost center 3 | 40 | Cost center 3 | Account 2 | 1) Project Revenue | 0 | Indirect Costs | 0 | 600000 |
| Business Unit 1 | Account 1 | 3) Other Revenue | 0 | Cost center 1 | 30 | Cost center 1 | Account 1 | 3) Other Revenue | 0 | Indirect Costs | 0 | 0 |
| Business Unit 1 | Account 1 | 2) Project Cost | -80000 | Cost center 2 | 30 | Cost center 2 | Account 1 | 2) Project Cost | 0 | Indirect Costs | 0 | -80000 |
| Business Unit 1 | Account 1 | 2) Project Cost | -80000 | Cost center 3 | 40 | Cost center 3 | Account 1 | 2) Project Cost | 0 | Indirect Costs | 0 | -80000 |
| Business Unit 1 | Account 1 | 4) Other Costs | 0 | Cost center 1 | 30 | Cost center 1 | Account 1 | 4) Other Costs | -120000 | Indirect Costs | -36000 | -36000 |
| Business Unit 1 | Account 2 | 2) Project Cost | -110000 | Cost center 2 | 30 | Cost center 2 | Account 2 | 2) Project Cost | 0 | Indirect Costs | 0 | -110000 |
| Business Unit 1 | Account 2 | 2) Project Cost | -110000 | Cost center 3 | 40 | Cost center 3 | Account 2 | 2) Project Cost | 0 | Indirect Costs | 0 | -110000 |
| Business Unit 1 | Account 1 | 5) Cost of work | -210000 | Cost center 1 | 30 | Cost center 1 | Account 1 | 5) Cost of work | -210000 | Indirect Costs | -63000 | -273000 |
| Business Unit 1 | Account 1 | 3) Other Revenue | 0 | Cost center 2 | 30 | Cost center 2 | Account 1 | 3) Other Revenue | 0 | Indirect Costs | 0 | 0 |
| Business Unit 1 | Account 2 | 1) Project Revenue | 600000 | Cost center 1 | 30 | Cost center 1 | Account 2 | 1) Project Revenue | 0 | Indirect Costs | 0 | 600000 |
| Business Unit 1 | Account 1 | 3) Other Revenue | 0 | Cost center 3 | 40 | Cost center 3 | Account 1 | 3) Other Revenue | 0 | Indirect Costs | 0 | 0 |
| Business Unit 1 | Account 2 | 3) Other Revenue | 0 | Cost center 2 | 30 | Cost center 2 | Account 2 | 3) Other Revenue | 0 | Indirect Costs | 0 | 0 |
| Business Unit 1 | Account 2 | 3) Other Revenue | 0 | Cost center 3 | 40 | Cost center 3 | Account 2 | 3) Other Revenue | 0 | Indirect Costs | 0 | 0 |
| Business Unit 1 | Account 2 | 2) Project Cost | -110000 | Cost center 1 | 30 | Cost center 1 | Account 2 | 2) Project Cost | 0 | Indirect Costs | 0 | -110000 |
| Business Unit 1 | Account 2 | 3) Other Revenue | 0 | Cost center 1 | 30 | Cost center 1 | Account 2 | 3) Other Revenue | 0 | Indirect Costs | 0 | 0 |
| Business Unit 1 | Account 1 | 4) Other Costs | 0 | Cost center 2 | 30 | Cost center 2 | Account 1 | 4) Other Costs | -120000 | Indirect Costs | -36000 | -36000 |
| Business Unit 1 | Account 1 | 4) Other Costs | 0 | Cost center 3 | 40 | Cost center 3 | Account 1 | 4) Other Costs | -120000 | Indirect Costs | -48000 | -48000 |
| Business Unit 1 | Account 2 | 4) Other Costs | 0 | Cost center 2 | 30 | Cost center 2 | Account 2 | 4) Other Costs | -120000 | Indirect Costs | -36000 | -36000 |
| Business Unit 1 | Account 2 | 4) Other Costs | 0 | Cost center 3 | 40 | Cost center 3 | Account 2 | 4) Other Costs | -120000 | Indirect Costs | -48000 | -48000 |
| Business Unit 1 | Account 2 | 4) Other Costs | 0 | Cost center 1 | 30 | Cost center 1 | Account 2 | 4) Other Costs | -120000 | Indirect Costs | -36000 | -36000 |
| Business Unit 1 | Account 1 | 5) Cost of work | -210000 | Cost center 2 | 30 | Cost center 2 | Account 1 | 5) Cost of work | -465000 | Indirect Costs | -139500 | -349500 |
| Business Unit 1 | Account 1 | 5) Cost of work | -210000 | Cost center 3 | 40 | Cost center 3 | Account 1 | 5) Cost of work | -210000 | Indirect Costs | -84000 | -294000 |
| Business Unit 1 | Account 2 | 5) Cost of work | -245000 | Cost center 1 | 30 | Cost center 1 | Account 2 | 5) Cost of work | -210000 | Indirect Costs | -63000 | -308000 |
| Business Unit 1 | Account 2 | 5) Cost of work | -245000 | Cost center 2 | 30 | Cost center 2 | Account 2 | 5) Cost of work | -210000 | Indirect Costs | -63000 | -308000 |
| Business Unit 1 | Account 2 | 5) Cost of work | -245000 | Cost center 3 | 40 | Cost center 3 | Account 2 | 5) Cost of work | -120000 | Indirect Costs | -48000 | -293000 |

Merge itself has return me a reasonable results, but I need to create pivot that will report TOTAL PNL 2023 of BU itself (example of red colored values from table) and INDIRECT COSTS of each corresponding CC that I've calculated amount of costs to be allocated from- something like this:
[image]

Problem are multiplied rows which I don't know how to properly "recalculate" or something, to get me uniqe values of PNL 2023. I'm really stucked at this step so any help or any advise upon how to approcah this challenge will be much appreciated!

UPDATE : my current PIVOT TABLE:
[image]

which presents tagged part of my desired pivot table from instruction:
[image]

I'm facing huge issue in relation to adding BU's TOTAL PNL and BU'S adjusted PNL (total - indirect costs) to upper level of pivot table.

I guess this is feasable with my appended table at the top of my question.

thank you all!

Comment: Your screenshots of data is almost useless for providing assistance. It cannot be copy/pasted into a worksheet. One can try an OCR program, or manually enter it. Having to do either of these is discouraging to those who might assist you. To make the data useful edit your question to post it as text, perhaps using this [Markdown Tables Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables), [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: @RonRosenfeld : agree, my bad. I've edited my data to markdown table and now its even worse, eventhough my preview shows table smoothly.

Comment: Fixed your table. If your problem is duplicated data, you can handle that either in the Power Query merge process, or by using the `Remove Duplicates` tool.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld thanks again. My major problem is not removing duplicate, since actually there is none taking all columns into consideration. What I want to achieve is to pivot this table into structure from my post.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to handle the repeated values for [PNL 2023]. You will need to create a measure for this.

Try something like:

```
BU/Acc/Flow PNL 2023:=
  var tbl = SUMMARIZE('YourTable', [BU/CC], [Account], [Flows], "PNL23", MAX([PNL 2023]))
  return SUMX(tbl, [PNL23])
```

Comment: Thank you @SamNseir. I've managed to calculate sum of repeated values and continued with creating pivot table,but I still don't know how to set total from the pivot example in my question.

Comment: Can you share a screen grab of your actual pivot table with the fields pane so we can see how it is constructed? (update your question with it.) And which version of Excel are you using?

Comment: i've updated my question with my so far created pivot table.